# select subquery in mysql where table2 is one column of table1

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

sorry i can't speak english very good but i have one question,

---

i have a table with name "myadv", this is main table, and i have about 30-35 subsidiary table that related to "myadv", 
in "myadv" is a column whit name "tbl", this column keeps "name of table thta relate to any rows"

(for example: for id=x ,  tbl= table1 and for id=y tbl=table2 and ...)
now i want select from "myadv" and "myadv.tbl" Simultaneously (whit one query)
plz help for solve this problom

this is my query but it don't work

```
SELECT *
  FROM `main_t`,
       (SELECT `col` FROM `main_t` WHERE `id`=?) AS `t`
  WHERE `id`=?
```

thanks for your help

Comment: would you please provide us with sample input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting design, but I don't think you can do what you're trying to do. To accomplish this you'd need to write a query which writes and executes another query based on the data from `myadv`, and I don't know of a way to make that work. I suspect that there's a better way to do what you're attempting to do but without understanding your data it's difficult to advise you. If you can edit your question and add additional information about your `myadv` table and the tables which relate to it we might be able to help.

Also, I don't understand how the query you posted which fetches data from `main_t` relates to your question about using a table named `myadv`.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem but it,s work only when run in wamp sql

---

SET @y = CONCAT('SELECT `col` FROM ',(select `tbl` from `main_t` where   `main_id`='100'),' where id=100 into @outvar');
   PREPARE `stmt` from @y;
   EXECUTE `stmt`;
   select @outvar;

---

how i can query that ready with prepare of mysql, execute of php?